# How to prove that at least two of the numbers $x,y,z$ are within $\frac{1}{2}$ unit from one another?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Let $x,y,z$ be real numbers with $0<x<y<z<1$. Prove that at least two of the numbers $x,y,z$ are within $\frac{1}{2}$ unit from one another.

I guess I'll have to prove this by contradiction. However what does it mean that "at least two of the numbers $x,y,z$ are within $\frac{1}{2}$ unit from one another."?

Comment: If $y-x> 1/2$ you know $y>1/2$

Comment: it means that either $|x -y| \leq \frac{1}{2}$ or $|x-z| \leq \frac{1}{2}$ or $|y-z| \leq \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: What's your question? You seem to ask what the statement means but have accepted an answer showing how to prove it.

Comment: Both questions "What does ... mean", "How to prove ...", the first was answered in the comments, the second in that question.

Comment: Of note, if you can't understand how, then by definition you're incapable of understanding the answers. Perhaps you meant you don't understand how to prove a certain statement?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about pigeon hole principle?  Split the interval $(0,1)$ in half.  If one is $\frac{1}{2}$, you are done since it is close enough to everything.  So now you have three numbers to stick into two boxes.  Two have to go into the same box and are therefore within $\frac{1}{2}$ of each other.

Comment: This is so good I had to disbelieve it first

Comment: Nice, clever application of PHP. +1

Comment: Ah, the pigeonhole principle… If there are more holes than pigeons then there's a pigeon with at least two holes in it.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly, Assume that this is not true and so  $y-x > \frac{1}{2}$ then this means that $y > x + \frac{1}{2}$ but since we know that $x > 0$ then this implies that $y > \frac{1}{2}$

Also assume that $z-y > \frac{1}{2}$ and so $z > y + \frac{1}{2}$ . However, since we showed that $y > \frac{1}{2}$ so $z > \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}$ and so  $z > 1$ which contradicts the fact that $z <1$

Answer (score 0):

$0<x<y\wedge y-x>\frac12\implies y>\frac12$

$y<z<1\wedge z-y>\frac12\implies y<\frac12$

Contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since $0<x,$ then $-x<0,$ so $$z-x<z-0=z<1.\tag{$\star$}$$

Proceeding by contradiction, then, is fairly straightforward. Suppose that each of $|x-y|,|y-z|,|x-z|\ge\frac12.$ Since $x<y<z,$ then $|x-y|=y-x$ and $|y-z|=z-y,$ whence by assumption, $$\frac12\le y-x\tag{1}$$ and $$\frac12\le z-y.\tag{2}$$ But then by $(1)$ and $(2)$ we have $$1=\frac12+\frac12\le y-x+z-y=z-x,$$ which by $(\star)$ yields $1<1,$ and we have a contradiction.